# SSLHandshakeException in the logs

Tags: ssl

Seeing this error message in Logs, can any one tell whats happening

"javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed"

this error message in logs started showing up when the certificate was expired.
I got the new certificate, generated truststore file and replaced the old one in the host.
still the same error. Any one know how to fix this.

Previously before the certificate was expired out environment was fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused.

Do you see this error logged in a client application that connects to this host? If so, then you'll need to replace the private key entry in the server's identity key store, not its trust store.

Or perhaps this message is logged by the server because you are using client authentication. In that case, you'd need to update the client's identity key store.

Comment: There are two applications, One is mine(x) and the other is owned by messaging team(y). My application(x) talks to application (y). between both of them there are certificates. when these certificate expired we started see that error message i posted above. After the new certificate is been placed, still seeing the error message. Any idea which side the problem is

Comment: My Application is logging the error, It is able to find the certificate and returining the error. But for some reason its not seeing the new cert file